# File Sharing with Encryption, how to send also the key to the receiver safely?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, cryptography, file-sharing

I am having trouble with my system. My app will basically do 4 things:

1. Send any file (even encrypted)
2. Encrypt any file
3. Receive incoming file
4. Decrypt encrypted files

My problem is, after the receiver receive the encrypted file and must input a key to decrypt it, how do I create a conditional statement if the original key from the sender is equal or not equal to the input from the receiver without the receiver getting any information about the key since they are the same app but the receiver app has no knowledge of that specific string.

All I can think of is creating a text file that contains the key and for the receiver to read the contents of that file to get the key, ultimately only for that conditional matching of keys. I am very confused but I saw that it works in an android app called ES File explorer. I encrypted a file using ES file explorer, then sent it with SHAREit and then decrypted it with another phone, and when I input the wrong key, the app knew that the key I input was wrong, without internet.

Answer (score 0):

There are two common ways to determine if the correct encryption key was used:

- HMAC (Hashed Message Authentication Code) - Encrypt your file and then run it through an HMAC (usually with SHA256 or another from the SHA family).  Prepend the resulting hash to your encrypted file.  **Always** apply the HMAC **after** encryption.  The receiver can then compute this same HMAC to determine if the key they were using is the correct one.  Remember to use a time-safe comparison function to compare the resulting hashes to avoid timing attacks.
- AEAD Block Modes - While encrypting, use a block mode like GCM or CCM.  This is the preferred option.  These block modes handle all of the data authentication for you.  GCM is usually preferred.  Careful nonce generation is required here however, as using the same nonce/key pair for two different encryption operations can trivially leak the plaintext.

EDIT:  Please see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46986977/how-to-use-password-to-decode-a-string/46987382#46987382) which details a secure approach to the problem you've asked about.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is the most correct one but I don't think I have yet the sufficient knowledge and programming skill to fully use the ways you stated. I am actually a student and I will definitely appreciate any tutorials for the steps you mentioned. Thank you sir!

Comment: No worries, please see my edit.  The code in the linked answer details a secure approach to encrypt files in GCM mode.

Comment: @LukePark Login behind applying the hash after encryption (to the encrypted file)?

Comment: @JAAAY I don't understand what you're asking sorry?

Comment: @LukePark You say "Always apply the HMAC after encryption." What is the purpose of doing it? For me this only makes sense if you apply it to the original file not the encrypted one

Comment: @JAAAY See [this answer](https://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac&ved=0ahUKEwieoN_w48zXAhUCo5QKHT3aCUIQjjgIKTAA&usg=AOvVaw1f5LftKV5wQX8aF1VGClKU).

Comment: @LukePark Encrypt-then-MAC is not what is needed in that case because intention of this is to just provide/verify the integrity of the data sent. He doesn't want to verify the integrity of the data, he just wants to be able to know if the password user provided is correct. In other words he wants to know if the data he will decrypt with a wrong key are correct or not. This is MAC-then-Encrypt's use. Think of it.

Comment: @JAAAY I'm afraid I disagree.  Feel free to edit your answer.

Comment: @LukePark Can you explain the me your 'algorithm' of what you do in order to decide whether the password I entered is correct or not in the Encrypt-then-MAC case when I hit a wrong password?